# How to Take Error Exit Path on Data Flow Task in SSIS Data Tools

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012-datatools

I'm downloading CSV files using FTP and I loop through them to import into a MS SQL staging table.
What I want to do is move successfully imported files into an **archive folder** and move failed files into a **failed folder**.

My problem is that I can't find a way to have a red error/failure arrow coming out of my Data Flow Task, and inside the Data Flow task, where I can see the red arrow coming out of the OLE DB task, I can't find a way to have a File System Task!

Am I missing something obvious?

[image: Data Flow Task]

[image]

Comment: Sorry... figured it out... I said I was missing something. How do I delete this question from my history???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just grab a green arrow coming out, connect it to the next step and then right-click on the green arrow and change it to Failure.